# How to install specified version of Composer

Tags: ubuntu, composer-php

How to install Composer v1.1.1 in Ubuntu? I have tried below one but its always installed latest version of Composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 36):

If you are using a docker container the following method would be better:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.10.16
```

Ensure you have **curl** installed before using this method. This was tested on ubuntu 20.04 Docker container.

Answer (score 10):

As per composer doc using `composer-setup.php` is prefered method how to install composer, I like to use one line with curl and passing params to get latest 1.x or 2.x

By following you get latest 1.x version
`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --1`

And for 2.x you either skip version or pass `--2`
`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --2`

Then you can run your composer version like
`php composer.phar`

Comment: and then move the composer.phar to a path so available on command line.
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--version` option when you're running `composer-setup.php`:

```
php composer-setup.php --version=1.1.1
```

See https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing - after the composer V2 version upgrade - using the `-- version`  parameter seems to be the only option to build a docker image including the [composer-asset-plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/fxp/composer-asset-plugin) needed in some modern framework like Yii2

This is a docker image example code:

```sh
# Install composer

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
        --install-dir=/usr/local/bin \
        --filename=composer --version=1.10.16 && \
        composer global require --optimize-autoloader \
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4.6" \
        "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3.10" && \
        composer global dumpautoload --optimize && \
        composer clear-cache
```